# DistinctCount On A specific condition In Power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I need to take the DistinctCount(InvNumber) of a InvNumber column by creating a new measures that is  #NoofInvoice, 
I need to show that column In MY report, but Column #NoofInvoice I want to take on Condition that If(OrderType='SALES' and OrderType is a column which contain two values SALES and RETURN or then only I need distinctcount(InvNumber)) in Power bi

Comment: Have you tried something like `CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(...), FILTER(..., [condition]))`?

Answer (score 3):

How about if you create a new measure called "No. of Invoices" like this:

```
No. of Invoices = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(InvNumber), FILTER(Table_Name, 'Table_Name'[OrderType] = "Sales"))
```

Let me know how you go with it! :)

Comment: This is useful to anyone who is searching for DISTINCTCOUNTX. I wanted to count trailing average users in a 30 day period and this enabled me to do so.